# How to read json data using scala from kafka topic in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new spark, Could you please let me know how to read json data using scala from kafka topic in apache spark.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried something already?

Comment: I tried using the following code:    case class MyClass(id:String, 
                       endtime:String, 
                       host:String, 
                       starttime:String, 
                       appservername:String, 
                       appname:String, 
                       classname:String, 
                       method:String, 
                       eventdate:String, 
                       executiontime:String, 
                       threadid:String)

Comment: implicit val myClassFormat = Json.format[MyClass]
   
    //  val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
     val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topic)
             .map(m => Json.parse(m._2).as[MyClass])

Comment: And what problem do you have? Add details to your question for better odds of a good answer.

Comment: @Bhaskar Please mark my answer as accepted if you think it works, else please let me know any issues with it.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest method would be to make use of the DataFrame abstraction shipped with Spark.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
                  ssc, kafkaParams, Set("myTopicName"))

stream.foreachRDD(
  rdd => {
     val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(rdd.map(_._2)) //converts json to DF
     //do your operations on this DF. You won't even require a model class.
        })
```

Answer (score 5):

I use [Play Framework's library for Json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson). You can add it to your project as a [standalone module](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11). Usage is as follows:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

case class MyClass(field1: String,
                   field2: Int)

implicit val myClassFormat = Json.format[MyClass]

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](...here are your params...)    
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, Set("myTopicName"))
  .map(m => Json.parse(m._2).as[MyClass])
```