# How to define the parameters inside of KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new in spark and kafka and I want to forward data in format of json from kafka to spark in stream. My problem is in defining the map of data and also how to define the parameters inside of KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConfig, Seconds(10))
case class dataMap (number: Int, address: String, product: String, store: String, seller : String)
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[ Int, String, String, String, String](ssc, kafkaParams, topics).map(m => m.as[dataMap])
```

when I am using the above code I am receiving following error:

```
error: type arguments [Int,String,String,String,String] conform to the bounds  of none of the overloaded alternatives of value createDirectStream
```

P.S : I have defined kafkaParams and topics in right format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, dataMap](...)
```

Note that that will get rid of your error, but you have more work to do. All that's going to do is get you the raw JSON `String`. You then have to convert the `String` into your `case class`. Honestly that's a separate question and has nothing to do with Apache Spark -- or even Kafka for that matter. You can find a couple of different solutions for that problem here: [How to read json data using scala from kafka topic in apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424724/how-to-read-json-data-using-scala-from-kafka-topic-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Then in this case, Should I change Kafkaparams configuration? my last config was :     val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](...)

Comment: I wouldn't think so. You said you are reading JSON, so I assume you are reading Strings -- and I also assumed both your Kafka keys and message values are Strings. So that covers the first four type values `String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder` -- they last type value is your `case class`. Now that I think about it, you have more work to do. You can't just do `map(m => m.as[dataMap])`. `m` is going to be a `String`. You will need to use a `JSON` parser to convert `m` to an instance of `dataMap`.